# Variable may not have been initialized error inside method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method which calculates the total sum of all the elements in array scores. When I compile this I get a "Variable may not have been initialized error" even though I've already declared it within the method

```
public double getTotal() {
        double total;
        for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i=i+2) {
            total = scores[i] + scores[i+1];
            
        }
        
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Yes you have *declared* it, but you didn't make sure to *initialize* it. What would happen if `scores.length == 0`? Also, what is the loop there for exactly anyways? Because you are not 
 actually summing up the total.

Comment: I didn't think of that. It gives a massive error if I try to create the array with length 0

Comment: My loop must be wrong also so

Comment: Yep I apologise for posting this. I just had to let total =0. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes you have *declared* it, but you didn't make sure to *initialize* it. What would happen if `scores.length == 0`? Then you would try to return `total`, which is `null` at this point.

If you are trying to sum up the contents of your `scores`, then it should probably look something like this:

```
public double getTotal() {
    double total = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        total += scores[i];    
    }
    return total;
}
```